# ImageView restore background color for recycled views

Tags: android, imageview, background-color, reset, convertview

in my Android App I use an AlertBox for selecting icons.
This is done with a custom Adapter. I have a class comming from ImageView which changes the backgrond color for the old selected icon.

All works fine expect that I nees to reset the background color for converted views in the adapter. getBackGroundDrawable always return null? Any idea ???

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    JIconImageView imageView = ((convertView == null) ? new JIconImageView(m_context) : (JIconImageView)convertView);

    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
    imageView.setIsSelected(m_selected == position);
    imageView.setImageResource(JEntryIconHelper.getIconFromIndex(position));

    return imageView;
}
```

and from public final class JIconImageView extends ImageView`enter code here`

```
public void setIsSelected(boolean bSelected)
{
    if (m_bSelected = bSelected)
        setBackgroundColor(SELECTED_BACKCOLOR);
    else setBackgroundDrawable(m_background);
}
```

Comment: Did you mean == in (m_bSelected = bSelected) ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no easy way to get the current theme background color.

One reliable way to do what you want is to save the original background color in a member variable during getView (or you could do this once, earlier, by creating a throwaway JIconImageView).  For example, at the point where you bind the adapter:

```
JIconImageView imageView = new JIconImageView (...);
Drawable origBackground = imageView.getBackground();
imageView = null;
```

Then, reference imageView.getBackground() in setIsSelected().

---

Another way would be to use an xml selector; this goes in your "drawables" folder:

```
<selector 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item 
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/your_selected_drawable" />

  <item 
    android:drawable="@drawable/your_unselected_drawable" />
</selector>
```

As you can see, this solution uses drawables rather than colors but, if your icons are fixed size, that is a trivial difference (maybe something similar can be done with colors -- you'll have to research that).  The drawback to this method is that you have now hard coded the background colors.  At least the definitions are in your resources, though.

---

You could build on the above by referencing an android style in your icon definition, something like this:

```
<JIconImageView
  android:id=...
  android:background="@drawable/jicon_background_selector />
```